# How to overcome maximum string length of 256 chars in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is table

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FotoAnons](
   [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [StoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
   [Foto] [char](50) NULL,
   [FotoDesc] [char](300) NULL,
   [Text] [text] NULL,
   [Vrema] [char](30) NOT NULL,
   [Organizator] [char](100) NOT NULL,
   [Logo] [char](50) NULL,
   [Adress] [char](500) NULL,
   [Link] [char](50) NULL,
   [Gis] [bit] NULL,
   [Organizator1] [char](100) NULL,
   [Logo1] [char](50) NULL,
   [Adress1] [char](500) NULL,
   [Link1] [char](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FotoAnons] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
   [ID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

 GO
```

I try to download table in the same way

```
  SELECT LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([ID] AS VARCHAR(40)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([StoryID] AS VARCHAR(40)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Foto]AS VARCHAR(40)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([FotoDesc] AS VARCHAR(300)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Text]AS VARCHAR(1000)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Vrema]AS VARCHAR(40)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Organizator] AS VARCHAR(40)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Logo] AS VARCHAR(150)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Adress] AS VARCHAR(250)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Link] AS VARCHAR(150)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Gis] AS VARCHAR(250)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Organizator1]AS VARCHAR(250)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Logo1] AS VARCHAR(250)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Adress1] AS VARCHAR(1000)),'NULL')))
    +'#'+LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(CAST([Link1] AS VARCHAR(500)),'NULL')))  
    + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
  FROM [story].[dbo].[FotoAnons]
```

Unfortunately result length of each row is 256 chars.

However if I download a couple of rows

```
FROM [story].[dbo].[FotoAnons] 
WHERE ID in (1,2)
```

I get the correct results with long strings.

I use an ancient version of SQL Server:

```
  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1779.0 (X64)   Nov 12 2008 12:10:04   
  Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  
  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 <X64> (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

but it stores real terabytes commercial data and no way to change version of that SQL Server.

[image: Wrong result]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: 2008 has no such maximum string length. My guess is that you are using some tool that truncates display to that length

Comment: I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 ) and simple doing save result as file

Comment: Maybe there is an option to set the max col width there but best to just use the export option in SSMS instead of doing that anyway

Comment: Thank you. @MartinSmith. This is solution! Options->Query Result -> Result to Text. Sorry to my stupid question.

Comment: I appreciate that there are times you can't upgrade, but *why* are you running CU2??? There are almost **13 years** of bug fixes and security patches you haven't applied!

Comment: And a beta version of SSMS as well.

Comment: Why don't you just install the latest version of SSMS 18? I believe it will still connect with SQL 2008.

Comment: I must admit, it doesn't even look like a supported version of Windows. Look like it's pre Windows XP... I, as a result, doubt SSMS 18 would run on such old technology, @Stu . The OP *really* needs to got those updates and upgrades sorted.

Comment: @Larnu . This is FREE windows version (Win2008). More than 10 years server windows was be full free and activation key can be download from subscription for anybody. A couple year MS change their policy and decide - NO free windows. Forbidd free Windows MS decide for better promoting  ASP.NET CORE (ASP.NET for Linux). MS changing their policy to opposite direction each couple year - for example VB.NET unexpectedly is not need, Classic ASP.NET unexpectedly is not need, Visual Designer support in Visual Studio is not need, free Windows for server is not need and so on.

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying there, @Alex . Though Windows 2008 was never "free".

Comment: @Larnu. And no need to any upgrade of free server windows from MS. It still working fine and even new projects I place to free Windows (if this is NET.Framework projects) or to Linux (if this is NET CORE projects).

Comment: So you willingly want to expose yourself, and your clients, to security risks? An odd choice. Hopefully you aren't dealing with any clients that follow GDPR laws, as you would most certainly be breaking them.

Comment: Dear @Larnu. Windows 2008 is a full (absolutely) free server windows. All my old key still working. And as I mention I place even my new projects to FREE Win2008. And I see "genuine windows" label. No crack, of course. Server windows was be free more than 10 years and still free now.

Comment: That's not "Free" @Alex ; the licence has been paid for. And that software you are using is riddled with security vulnerabilities. Like I mentioned, you haven't updated (not upgraded) your SQL instance in almost **13 years**; I dread to think how out date your 2008 Windows is...

Comment: @Larnu, GDPR is not related to MS Policy. Once MS decide Win2008 is free, then a couple years after MS decide Win2008 is not free for promoute ASP.NET for Linux. What relation GDPR of this MS decision?

Comment: You are using unsupported software, and storing your clients data on it, @Alex . The data is insecure as a result, and that is exasperated by your choice to still being running CU2 (that came out in November 2008!). You're not even patched against Spectre and Meltdown. That has everything to do with GDPR...

Comment: @Larnu. No-no-no. I can deploy ASP.NET for Linux (NET CORE application) even to Freebsd 4.0 (from 2000 year). And all be working fine and secure (of course need to install patch for support modern cryptography to support TSL 1.2). This is question ONLY about money for MS.

Comment: You clearly are not using Linux above, @Alex . SQL Server wasn't supported on Linux until SQL Server 2017... You're not going to listen to sense here, but I still strongly suggest you get off that OS and SQL Server version. or at least, ***PLEASE***, apply the latest updates (you have 11 years of them to apply).

Comment: Dear @Larnu. I deploy my NET CORE application to FREEBSD and Linux. And very often use MS SQL server. I'm very sad, but you don't understand even how ASP.NET Developer for Linux use SQL2000 and SQL2005. It common the most popular technic. In computer with any ancient MS SQL you need create WCF-service. This is extremely simple, usually need only couple of mouse click and never need more than 5 minutes. Then in ASP.NET need to create link to WCF service, usually this spend about 10 seconds. And ups... any NET CORE apps (even deployed on FreeBSD) working secure and fine with SQL2000 and SQL2005

Comment: @Larnu. And this ancient SQL2005 server working EXACTLY with Linux web server and frontend in NET CORE 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

According to clue of Martin Smith, this is restriction of MS SMS

[image: MS SMS Restriction]